# How to resolve missing dependencies in Maven/sbt/ivy?

Tags: maven, sbt, jxbrowser

How can I resolve these missing dependencies in Maven/sbt/ivy ?
These are some dependencies which SBT cant resolve. They seem to be dependencies of dependencies from [this build.sbt](http://pastebin.com/xnd3xinA).

Where can i find the remaining dependencies?

When these dependencies are dependencies of my dependencies those dependencies should have existed once.

```
unresolved dependency: com.teamdev#jxbrowser;5.2: not found
unresolved dependency: com.teamdev#development-license;5.2: not found
unresolved dependency: com.jgoodies#jgoodies-forms;1.9.0: not found
unresolved dependency: com.jgoodies#jgoodies-common;1.8.1: not found
unresolved dependency: javagraphics#JBreadCrumb;1.0: not found
unresolved dependency: com.microsoft#sqljdbc41;4.1: not found
unresolved dependency: commons-logging#commons-logging-adapters;1.1: not found
download failed: maven-plugins#maven-cobertura-plugin;1.3!maven-cobertura-plugin.plugin
download failed: maven-plugins#maven-findbugs-plugin;1.3.1!maven-findbugs-plugin.plugin
```

Comment: Can you share your xml file?

Comment: have a look at the build.sbt mentioned in the question

Comment: Just sanity checking here. You do have internet connection when compiling? One way to delve deeper is to use [sbt-dependency-graph](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph). You can create an XML using the `ivy-report` task and follow the recursive dependencies of each library.